# Am I considered to be cancelling a solution in here when I did the another method which is squaring both sides or not?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

> Solve $2\ln(3x+5)=4$

The second method is:

$\ln(3x+5)^2=4$,
$\implies \ln(3x+5)=2$,
$\implies e^2=3x+5$,
$\implies x= \frac{e^2-5}{3}$

which equals only $ 0.796$, and there is not another answer (assuming if it is not rejected)
This is not an exam's question; I already have the answer and know it, but what I am asking now is that: when I squared both sides, am I considered to be canceling another solution, which is the $-4.13$ (assuming if it was not to be rejected as it is known that no $\ln$ for negative)? And if yes, I am considered to be canceling a solution; why is this possible?
And here is a picture of the whole thing I explained to be clearer.

[image]

Comment: ```$\ln$ ``` not Ln

Comment: Why squaring at all?  We have $\ln(3x+5)=2$ immediately.  And it's quite dangerous to "square" as fake solution may be introduced.  Consider $2\ln(x)=0$; clearly $x=1$ is the only solution whereas the equation $\ln(x^2)=0$ has solutions $x=\pm1$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any situation in which I would say that squaring an equation "cancels" a solution. It sometimes *introduces* extraneous "solutions" that you have to reject.

I suppose you could say that squaring sometimes forces you to "cancel a solution" later in the process.

In this case the rule "there is no $\ln$ of a negative number" does not apply,
since the thing you apply $\ln$ to is $3x + 5,$ which is positive as long as
$x > -5/3.$
Instead, you reject the negative square root because it implies that
the *output* of $\ln$ is negative, and in this case you know that
$\ln(3x+5)>0$ since it is multiplied by a positive number and produces a positive number.

So in the end you do "cancel a solution", not at the time when you square
$\ln(3x+5),$ but rather at the time when you take the square root of $4$
and write only the positive square root.